# Alternative for appendRow in Google App Script

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I have a lot of CSV files with data. With a Google App Script I add them together. The result is that I have an array of arrays in memory. I also do some filtering, and then paste the information in a new Spreadsheet. To do that, I use the `appendRow` method while looping:

```
uniqueRows.forEach(function(row) {
  outputSheet.appendRow(row);
});
```

Problem is, I run out of time and Google App Script crashes. Is there any alternative to solve this?

I know from Visual Basic that if you have a range, you can paste it in one step into a sheet, but now I have an array of arrays in memory.
Other alternative would be, instead of pasting the information in one file, paste it in multiple files. But first I would like t know if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Use `Range#setValues` and pass your rectangular 2D array. This (writing arrays from memory) is a core use case of apps script and is covered by the introductory guides one can find in the official documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your uniqueRows is a 2-dimensional array, where the first item contains all the values for that particular row you want to add. Then you should be able to do, get the exact range you want to start at and then write that array into the range:

```
var rowStart = outputSheet.getLastRow() + 1;

outputSheet
.getRange( rowStart, 1, uniqueRows.length, uniqueRows[0].length)
.setValues( uniqueRows )
```